# Error: Expected an identifier, in C with CCS for MSP430

Tags: c, msp430

I'm currently taking over a project for MSP430 that was previously compiled with MSPGCC, and I was asked to update it so it works with TI's C compiler using CCSv6. However, I'm getting a set of errors that I don't really understand. Here's a sample of my code where there are some errors:

```
struct UART_UCxxCTL_BITS
{
    UINT8_T UCSWRST : 1;    /**< R/W Software reset enable                  */
    UINT8_T UCTXBRK : 1;    /**< R/W Transmit break                         */
    UINT8_T UCTXADDR: 1;    /**< R/W Transmit address                       */
    UINT8_T UCDORM  : 1;    /**< R/W Dormant                                */
    UINT8_T UCBRKIE : 1;    /**< R/W Receive break character interrupt      */
    UINT8_T UCRXEIE : 1;    /**< R/W Receive eroneous-character interrupt   */
    UINT8_T UCSSEL  : 2;    /**< R/W USCI clock source select               */
    UINT8_T UCSYNC  : 1;    /**< R/W Synchronous mode select    */
    UINT8_T UCMODE  : 2;    /**< R/W Mode select                */
    UINT8_T UCSPB   : 1;    /**< R/W Stop bit select            */
    UINT8_T UC7BIT  : 1;    /**< R/W Character length           */
    UINT8_T UCMSB   : 1;    /**< R/W MSB first select           */
    UINT8_T UCPAR   : 1;    /**< R/W Parity select              */
    UINT8_T UCPEN   : 1;    /**< R/W Parity enable              */
};
```

For all these lines inside the struct, except for `UCMODE` and `UCSSEL`, I'm getting the error: "#41 expected an identifier"
In total, I have 38 errors #41 in my project, all of them on structs, but not every struct and not every declarations inside them. They appear in two header files, one for the UART and one for the SPI. These two files are not linked though. In both files structs are declared, some of them quite similar.

For instance, in both files, `UCMODE` and `UCSSEL` aren't considered as errors, but the rest is. That's what I find strange.

Please note that `UINT8_T` is an `unsigned char`.

Do you know what could bring these errors ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it possible they're being defined as macros elsewhere?

Comment: Try to narrow it down to the smallest self-contained source file that exhibits the error. You should be able to do it with a single bit field rather than the 14 in your example. You'll also need to include the definition of `UINT8_T` in the reduced source file (where is it defined, and why is it in all-caps?) Then copy-and-paste the exact error message into the question. Why is this tagged both C and C++?

Comment: The errors are present in two header files, one for the UART and one for the SPI.    `UINT8_T` is defined as unisgned char in an other header file used in most of the project. The exact error message is already in my question and are the only errors I have.

Comment: The size of that structure is 16 bits. You might as well use `UINT16_T` instead of `UINT8_T`.

Comment: It seems that changing the data type does not affect the errors. I've tried with `unisgned char`, `UINT16_T` and `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 0):

The failing keywords are already defined in CCS environment, in the processor header file, i.e. msp430f6725.h

```
#define UCRXEIE                (0x0020)       /* RX Error interrupt enable */
```